# What happened to only showing the suggested edits when there are 5 or more?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

On StackOverflow I thought it was set to only show the link when there were more than 5 suggested edits in the queue in order to keep it from being distracting.

Now it's showing up for every edit. Is this how it is supposed to be, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a mis-configuration, you should now only see the indicator if there are more than 5 in the queue (this number is subject to change in the future if we need to, and only applies to SO currently).

There is a build going out for the `>` vs `>=` piece of this as well, so it'll *effectively* be 6 for a few hours until that build happens, then it'll actually be a minimum of 5 on SO, and 0 everywhere else.